# Can an iPhone app receive battery notifications when running in background

Tags: iphone, background, battery

Can my iPhone app running in background receive battery notifications?

My app has registered for battery notifications:

- Battery notifications- `(void)batteryLevelDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification{[self.tableView reloadData];}`
- `(void)batteryStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification{[self.tableView reloadData];}`

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

No. That code will only be called while your app is in the foreground.